# Quando não usar Realm?

Tags: android, banco-de-dados, mobile, orm, realmdb

Em alguns testes de Benchmark, comparando Realm com o SQLite e alguns outros ORM de acordo com o site https://blog.realm.io/realm-for-android/ podemos ver um desempenho muito superior em relação aos outros banco de dados. Então aí que vem a minha questão:

- Quando não usar Realm ?
- Porquê seu desempenho de acordo com o site da realm.io é tão superior aos outros ?